# Android 4 settings style

Tags: java, android, xml, styles

I really like the androi 4 settings page and im trying to style my app the same way.
Here is a screenshot: http://cdn.androidtapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Android-4.0-Settings-Screen.jpg.

Ive just gotten into java and android 3 or 4 days ago so style i havent really focused on style and dont know anything about it so i have a couple of questions:

1) How to set similar caption to list (Wiress and network on the picture for example)

2) How to set the same colors to my app? Is this somekind of a default style?

3) Is padding used on the picture to make list distance from borders? Can padding be applied thought whole application or does it have to be defined in every xml?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can apply a universal style to your app (this includes padding), it's quite straightforward

look here for a starting point http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Yeah - definitely read that document (was about to answer that). You'll have a better understanding of styling and be better able to ask a specific question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style your app the same, you should follow these guidelines about standard metrics and grids:

http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

1) To set a similar caption you have to implement your own customized view and add it to your list.

2) You can set a theme you need in `AndroidManifest.xml` or you can use standard items. To find them have a look at android.jar/res.layout folder in your Android library in your project. There are all the standard layout files for Views.

3) What you need is to set margins in your layout-file.

You have to make a layout file and specify all the View-elements and margins in it.

However, if you want to make preferences there are ready classes available for that (PreferenceActivity or PreferenceFragment).

Comment: Are you sure its a custom thing? I have seen many aplications with exactly the same type of caption... maybe its default?

Comment: Yes, there is no default item like this, because it is very specific. All the android items are more general. You can have a look how it is implemented in the Android source code and implement them yourself, but this list element with switch and icon cannot be invoked from API.

Comment: The screenshot from your post is a PreferenceActivity or PreferenceFragment with a custom list item.